# MANET Routing protocol implementation in INET

Tags: omnet++, inet

According to the INET model [catalog](https://inet.omnetpp.org/Protocols.html), there are several versions of AODV and DYMO protocols, but there is only one folder in the INET source directory for AODV and DYMO. Does this mean that the implementation of AODV (1) and AODV (2) are merged into one code?

[image]

Edit: I found this post by Rudolf that might answer my question:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can find in the [changelog](https://github.com/inet-framework/inet/blob/394571fa32fb7be51342a89d6fc942247f89c037/WHATSNEW#L371), the INETMANET code was removed from the source tree. The formulation on the catalog page is a bit weird, but there usually the multiple entries refer to other projects that are not directly part of the INET source tree.

In this case, all the "manet stuff" was moved to INETMANET, as referenced in the text in your screenshot. However, as pointed out [here](https://github.com/inetmanet/inetmanet), this project has since died. Basically that means there is only one maintained version of AODV.

Comment: oh I see. AODV-UU was ported into INETMANET and then into INET. Eventually, they decided to remove it from the INET (starting from INET-3.3.0). But apparently they forgot to update the INET catalog; It is a little bit confusing.